# Pundit inheritance from another role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I've got a Rails project using Devise together with the really awesome [Pundit Gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). I'm using three different roles - Superadmin, Admin and User.

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow define that the superadmin has all the rights that the admin has plus more. So that I don't have to write `<% if current_user.admin? || current_user.superadmin? %>` in my views anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you are using `if current_user.admin? || current_user.superadmin?` in your views is a particularly stinky code smell that indicates that you are not using the authorization layer properly.

You should be using:

```
<% if policy(@post).update? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit post", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

And defining the rules in your policies - not spreading the authorization logic (who can do what) all over the place.

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  # ...
  def update?
    admin?
  end

  private 

  def admin?
    user.admin? || user.superadmin?
  end
end 

class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    super || record.author == user
  end
end
```

If you are using a role library like [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) you can also simplify this by giving the superadmins both an admin and superadmin role:

```
@user.add_role(:admin)
@user.add_role(:superadmin)
@user.has_role?(:admin) # true
```

Comment: thanks a lot! makes obviously much more sense to directly manipulate the policy!